# DockerFile: Passing an ARG to dotnet build for build-configuration

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm not able to utilize a Docker ARG in my DockerFile -- specifically when building a .net Core project:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk-nanoserver-1809 AS build
ARG target_configuration=Debug
WORKDIR /src
COPY MyProject/MyProject.csproj MyProject/
RUN dotnet restore MyProject/MyProject.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/MyProject
RUN dotnet build --configuration $target_configuration --no-restore -o /app MyProject.csproj
```

The **'$target_configuration'** is not substituted. I've tried various combinations of ${xx}, "$xx", "${xx}", etc, but I'm not winning.
FWIW, the message I get in this case is:

> warning MSB3052: The parameter to the compiler is invalid,
>   '/define:$TARGET_CONFIGURATION'

I'm aware of the limitation of ARGs not being available during container run-time (and associated need for an ENV variable), as well as the ARG not being available during build when defined BEFORE the FROM statement, however these are not applicable here (I believe).

What am I doing wrong?

Docker Environment:

```
Server: Docker Engine - Community
Engine:
  Version:          18.09.2
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.10.6
  Git commit:       6247962
  Built:            Sun Feb 10 04:28:48 2019
  OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

---

***EDIT:***

(TL;DR) **Use %var% for Windows images**

Docker RUN runs within a specified container, which means that the shell that command is running in affects how variable substitution is done. So for Windows containers, use %var%

[This](https://forums.docker.com/t/unable-to-consume-arg-or-env-variables-in-run-commands/25467?u=ive) thread in the Docker-Forum has a little more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is probably running as an exe, therefore try using it as an exe env

```
RUN dotnet build --configuration %target_configuration% ...
```

Comment: Thanks Efrat. Are you saying that because I'm on Windows and my Docker command is an exe, then docker's variable/argument substitution is different to if I ran it on Linux? Seems crazy.
Regardless, that WORKED. Knowing what to search for, I found this thread on the Docker forums...but I can't see this behaviour documented ANYWHERE.

https://forums.docker.com/t/unable-to-consume-arg-or-env-variables-in-run-commands/25467/4?u=ive

Comment: it should work on linux machines as well. the `RUN` instruction has nothing to do with your host - it is running inside the container, and since the container is from a microsoft-based image, i thought it might be running as cmd.exe. maybe you would like to edit your edit accordingly